# Unexpected result of right shift operators NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitwise-operators

I am aware that JS has `>>` apparently for signed-numbers shifts and `>>>` for unsigned.

I tested two simple examples in the node console:

```
a = 0b10000000000000000000000000000100
> a >> 31
-1
> a >>> 31
1
```

I've read mdn, w3schools, etc. But I expect both cases to be **1**.

Also, see a 31 bit number:

```
a = 0b1000000000000000000000000000010;
a>>30
1 
a>>>30
1
```

What is the mistake?

May be related to JS reading the number as 32Bits, and using that last bit as a sign?

```
> (a & a).toString(2)
'-1111111111111111111111111111100'
```

Comment: [Right shift (`>>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift): _"This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Copies of the leftmost bit are shifted in from the left. **Since the new leftmost bit has the same value as the previous leftmost bit, the sign bit (the leftmost bit) does not change. Hence the name "sign-propagating".**"_

Comment: @Andreas So where does the `-` come from?

Comment: "using that last bit as a sign", yes, the leftmost bit is for the sign, `1` is negative, `0` is positive.

Comment: @misterwtf thanks! that also explains why second test is both 1. The first bit is 0.

Comment: You may be interested in this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations.

Comment: @misterwtf will take a look, thanks